# Advance Search In github by issues count

Tags: git, github

I would like to search in GitHub for repos having x number of open/close issues and belong to language y.

I can search by language, but I don't see x number of issues filter.

Answer (score -1):

Try to search in GitHub this command: `issues:x`
for example: `issues:57`, in result you should find some issues with the number 57 (#57), than you can use the open/close filter and choose languages as well